# Empty Octomap in RGBDSLAM

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, octomap, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using rgbdslam_v2 with the Intel Realsense R200 on ROS Kinetic. It seems to be working fine and I am getting a point cloud in the RGBDSLAM GUI. However, when I turn off the cloud display to view the Octomap, it seems to be empty. Saving the Octomap also just saves an empty Octomap. I have tried enabling online octomapping and running the Point Cloud Occupancy Filter menu item (which I am not quite sure how is supposed to be used - is it for generating the Octomap when online octomapping is disabled?), but to no avail.

Is there something I have missed?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253630/empty-octomap-in-rgbdslam/) by [danmou](https://answers.ros.org/users/29235/danmou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2017-03-20**:
The voxel filter is meant to geometrically downsample the clouds. I guess it should better not be used with octomapping, might work though. Have you set the "store_pointclouds" parameter to false? It is true by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a same problem. Although i set "store_pointclouds" to false, the saved octomap file has no data. The saved octomap just include as follows.

```
# Octomap OcTree file
# (feel free to add / change comments, but leave the first line as it is!)
#
id ColorOcTree
size 0
res 0.5
data
```

I just click "Save Octomap" in the menu without clicking any other menu. I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04, Kinectic and rgbdslam v2 (https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2)

Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [robotsoft](https://answers.ros.org/users/30607/robotsoft/) with karma: 16 on 2017-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotsoft](https://answers.ros.org/users/30607/robotsoft/) on 2017-06-05**:
I solved this issue by adding `return true` in bool GraphManager::updateCloudOrigin(Node* node). This function needs to return a bool but `return true` is missed in the end of the function. The function can be found in graph_mgr_io.cpp. I finally have a binary octomap file.

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2017-09-30**:
Not solving I have tried to set the store_pointclouds option to false and then tried your method nothing changes

**Comment by [robotsoft](https://answers.ros.org/users/30607/robotsoft/) on 2017-10-02**:
You may try with setting store_pointclouds to true. It is helpful to post your saved octomap for solving this problem.

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2018-02-19**:
Thanks for the above answer the return true thing worked I got binary octomap